# Why am I getting an error upon assembling?

Tags: assembly, pep8-assembly

I am trying to translate global array *vector* but whenever I assemble it I get an error.  I am using indexed addressing and I don't understand why this is wrong.

[Figure 6.34](http://militarystudents.files.wordpress.com/2009/11/figure-6-34.png)

```
         DECO    vector,x   ;      << vector[i];ERROR: This instruction cannot have this addressing mode.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just received an answer via email and it was a problem with the addressing mode getting changed.  Redefining the mnemonics (via the system menu) remedied the situation.